# 'cv' script with arguments

Tags: cv

Is it possible to pass command-line arguments to a script that's being run with `cv`?  If I try the obvious thing and just pass the argument after the script name, I get this:

```
$ sudo -u daemon `which cv` scr find_contact_id.php foo

                                                              
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]      
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "script".  
                                                              

php:script [--level LEVEL] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER] [--] <script>
```

No difference if I put a `--` after the script name to try to separate arguments.  If I quote `"find_contact_id.php foo"` as the script, it says:

```
$ sudo -u daemon `which cv` scr "find_contact_id.php foo"
PHP Deprecated:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /bitnami/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.wikimedia.contacteditor/contacteditor.civix.php on line 246
Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /bitnami/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.wikimedia.contacteditor/contacteditor.civix.php on line 246
Failed to locate script: find_contact_id.php foo
```

Is there a way to do this?

My `cv` version info:

```
$ sudo -u daemon `which cv` --version
cv v0.3.27
```

**Update:** `cv` ticket "Feature request: command line arguments" posted at https://github.com/civicrm/cv/issues/133 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly pass arguments to `cv` scripts, but you can work around it:

`$ env CV_ARGS="arg1 arg2 arg3" cv scr my_script.php`

my_script.php:

```
<?php

$my_args = getenv("CV_ARGS");

var_dump($my_args);
```

Comment: That doesn't work so great, it will give a single string arg `"arg1 arg2 arg3"`.  You can split that, but splitting like the shell would do it is notoriously difficult to do properly.

Comment: Sure - you know what arguments you're passing to your script but mostly splitting on space is fine.  If you don't want to split just use multiple args: `env CV_ARG_1="arg1" CV_ARG_2="arg2" cv ...`

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate that this is the best one can do, but I'm going to submit a feature request for `cv`, because this isn't very satisfactory for general use.

Comment: Ticket posted at https://github.com/civicrm/cv/issues/133 .